# How to change a value of an array in Redux Store Slice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Slice to store locations in it. I declared 2 functions, set and setLocation. set takes an array of locations and setLocation should set one location.

This is sample data that is in locations variable:

```
const locations = [{name: '1', index: 0}, {name: '2', index: 1}];
```

This is my slice code:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const locationsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'locations',
    initialState: {
        locations: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        set: (state, locations) => {
            state.locations = locations.payload
        },
        setLocation: (state, location) => {
            state.locations[location.index] = location
        }
    },
})

export const { set, setLocation } = locationsSlice.actions
export default locationsSlice.reducer
```

The set(locations) call is working. But I can't replace a single location in the location array with setLocation(location), while location is one value out of the locations array.
When I do console.log(state.location) in the setLocation() function, I get some proxy object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem why you are getting `Proxy` in the `setLocation` action is because you pass `location.index` when searching for specific location, but you should pass `location.payload.index`.

```
setLocation: (state, location) => {
   state.locations[location.payload.index] = location
}
```